# How do you style iOS components?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

I am just getting started in iOS development after working in Android since the early days and I am a bit confused on how you style/skin iPhone components.

I saw that there is a way to change the color for some components (is that what they are called?) in properties but how can I go even further?

For example, how could I be designing a custom button, or custom listview?

Comment: Did you try searching for "ios custom button"? What did you find?

Comment: @GregHewgill is right, you need to search a little more before asking. BTW your question is far too general, since some of the UI components under iOS are easily customizable because Apple let the user do it simply with properties while other components have to be tweaked to be customized, and most of tweaks are specific to one component. Try searching "ios custom button" or "ios custom listview', etc. Think about giving a try to the interface builder too, for most of simple designing it can do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several elements here you are asking, so my answer might not be enough for everything you want.

You can for instance use this page here that give you a real nice tutorial for doing some customization to UI components:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

For UITableViews there are other steps you would have to take. For instance, this very good tutorial:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: the ray wenderlich tutorial really hurts my eyes, but really is the best tutorial for what the poster is asking for.

Comment: Hey, thanks those are very useful! Should have done a google search before :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If you create custom UI elements to replicate standard UI elements in
>   all but appearance, you should instead consider using the appearance
>   customization programming interfaces available in iOS 5 and later.

via [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

Which i suggest viewing [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html) to get the best understanding of the interface builder

---

For a Button as an image:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.png"];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myView addSubview:button];
```

or with the interface builder:

> select "Custom Button" as the type and then select the image you want
>   from a drop-down menu.

---